# How to upgrade glibc on 64 bit RHEL 5.4

Tags: linux, postgresql, glibc, rhel5

We are planning to upgrade postgres 9.0 to 9.4 rpm in Redhat Linux 5.4.
Its asking for glibc 2.6.

My env: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)
        current glibc version: glibc-2.5-118.el5_10.2

Is it possible to upgrade glibc to the latest version? or else 
is there any other way to upgrade postgress from 9.0 to 9.4 without upgrading glibc.

Please help me out.

Thanks,
Suresh

Comment: maybe you should try to ask this question on serverfault.com

Comment: Are you sure about version 5.4? That version was released September 2009. Latest version is 5.11, September last year. An update is appropriate after 5 years of bugs, security issues and fixes.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed on [serverfault.com](http://link%20statically(-static)%20use%20rpath.%20rpath%20overwrite%20the%20default%20search%20path(-rpath,/srv/myapp/lib)), don't replace your current glibc, instead install the glibc you need beside and link postgresql statically :

- Copy glibc 2.6 somewhere,
- link statically(-static)
- use rpath. rpath overwrite the default search path(-rpath,/srv/myapp/lib)